# Why does SharePoint not allow me to login to my test account?

Tags: 2007, login, authentication

I am trying to login to my testuser account through sign in as different user.  This gives me an error message saying that it is I am unauthorized to view this page even though the account has read permission.  Then I try to login to my full control account and it only succeeds after the third attempt.

This has only happened recently and there have been no major updates/patches applied to the server.  Has anyone encountered an issue like this?

Comment: Have you added a custom master page / content or style library item which is unpublished?

Comment: No, everything has been published that was customized.  I also tried elevating priviledges on the test account to contribute, but I was still unable to login to the account.

Comment: I sometimes have to add users to the "Style Resource Readers" group to get them to see the custom style library items

Comment: I was able to do it by going to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level -> Prompt for user name and password (at bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mauro is on to something here (see comment above).

Try and fire up Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) and see what exact request triggers the 401 (unauthorized). Could be an image or css that isnt published.

Comment: I got Fiddler and it showed that there were no requests requiring publishing, it was a problem with my internet explorer autologging in and not allowing me to log into any other account.

Comment: I'd like to add that Fiddler has helped me a lot in other areas besides this issue and wanted to accept your answer because of that.